# case insensitive regex returning original pattern

Tags: python, regex

If I am looking for a small list of words (these words change dynamically) in a paragraph and want a case insensitive search, I use a pattern like:

```
words = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse']
reg = re.compile(r"(?i)(\b)(?P<word>" + "|".join(words) + r")(\b)")
```

which turns into this pattern string:

```
r"(?i)(\b)(?P<word>Cat|Dog|Horse)(\b)"
```

This works to find a match in text like the following using re.search():

```
reg.search('I own a black cat named Sally.')
# Returns one match on 'cat'
```

How do I return the actual word in the original match pattern? In this case the word "Cat" with a capital C and not the word in the search text with a lowercase c.

Thanks

Comment: you look for `cat` with flag caseinsensivity and want to get `Cat` back regardless how it was spelled in the text you search trough?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for keywords that are stored in a db table. However they are capitalized in text, I want to match on them and then increment a counter in the database. The keywords are the index key so I want the regex match to return the keyword exactly as it appears in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

words = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse']
reg = re.compile(r"\b(?:(" + ")|(".join(words) + r"))\b", flags=re.I)

match = reg.search('My grandma owned no cats, only a black doG named Morli.'
                   ' Oh, and no horse, of course.')
if match:
    print(words[match.lastindex - 1])
```

prints

```
Dog
```

This builds a regex like `\b(?:(Cat)|(Dog)|(Horse))\b`, i.e., a non-capturing group (this is the meaning of `?:`) surrounded by word boundaries (the `\b`s), which is an alternation of capturing groups. The index of the last (and only, if any) matching capturing group is returned in [`match.lastindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.lastindex), but this is also the index in the `words` list (because of how the regex was constructed), except it is offset by 1 because group 0 is the full match.

The set of words found in the text is easily constructed by

```
words_found = {words[match.lastindex - 1] for match in reg.finditer(text)}
```

---

The following is an edit by Patrick Artner, of which I don't think it's an improvement - but I'll leave it here because it is food for thought.

Edit - pls, incorporate:

```
all_matches = reg.findall('My grandma owned no cat, only a black doG named Morli.A cat named tinker came by.'
                          ' Oh, and no horse, of course.')
found = [ words[idx] for k in all_matches for idx,m in enumerate(k) if m.strip()  ]

print(found) # ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Horse']
```

Comment: Have a look - with that it is about the same - w/o using a dict.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat clumsy with a workaround-dict that maps back from the regex-group-match to your original keyword - but should help you out:

```
import re

def getWordsFromText(text,keywords = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse']):
    """Builds a dict for keywords, returns the original spelling if something is found
    case insensitivly in the given text.

    Returns a (potentially empty) generator with results."""
    d = {w.lower():w for w in keywords}

    # pattern inspired by  Wiktor Stribiżew
    reg = re.compile(rf"\b(?:{'|'.join(d)}\b)", flags=re.I)
    for m in reg.finditer(text):
        yield d[m.group().lower()]

print(list(getWordsFromText('I own a black cat named Sally. And a dOg called Jack.')))
print(list(getWordsFromText('I own a blue whale named Sally.')))
```

Output:

```
['Cat', 'Dog']
[]
```

Comment: somewhat clumsy is an understatement

Comment: @WalterTross  ping me back when you posted your solution :)

Comment: I was going to post it, then I realised that yours essentially did what I had in mind, but was definitely written _much_ better

Comment: uhm, now that I think of it, there _is_ another solution... (although I don't think it's really better)

Comment: (... or maybe it is?)